Android add a array of strings (will be TextView) into two LinearLayout dynamically, when idx even add in first LinearLayout, when odd the second
I want add a array of strings (will be TextView) into two LinearLayout dynamically, when idx even add in first LinearLayout, when odd the second.
I define three members in MainActivity:
LinearLayout first;
LinearLayout second;
LinearLayout now;

and in the for loop of array of strings, do:
if(idx%2==0){
  now=first;
}else{
  now=second;
}
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new 
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
  textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
  textView.setText(strings[idx]);
  now.addView(textView);
});

But all TextView go to the first LinearLayout, and the second LinearLayout is empty. Why? I am new in java and android development. Can anyone help? Thank you!

The issue you're experiencing might be due to the way you are referencing the now variable within the runOnUiThread method. Since now is assigned within the for loop but used inside the runOnUiThread method, it might be that now is always referencing the same LinearLayout when the code inside runOnUiThread is executed.
To fix this, you can use a final variable inside the for loop to ensure that each iteration uses the correct reference for the now variable.
LinearLayout first;
LinearLayout second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    first = findViewById(R.id.first_linear_layout);
    second = findViewById(R.id.second_linear_layout);

    String[] strings = {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4"}; 

    for (int idx = 0; idx < strings.length; idx++) {
        final int index = idx; // Create a final variable for the index
        final LinearLayout now = (index % 2 == 0) ? first : second;
        
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            textView.setText(strings[index]); 
            now.addView(textView); 
        });
    }
}


I think that there would be no need of an extra linear layout. Just the other two first  and second would suffice.
Here's how:
LinearLayout first;
LinearLayout second;

for (int idx = 0; idx < strings.length; idx++) {
    final int index = idx;
        
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText(strings[index]); 
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            first.addView(textView);
        } else {
            second.addView(textView);
        }
    });
}

Using this way, I think you can achieve the desired results.
